# Mysql large database import

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqlimport

I am trying to import a database of 55 MB to mysql on localhost and DB in XML format and I am getting a out of memory error.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 549453824) (tried to allocate 485169255 bytes) in E:\XAAMP\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Error_Handler.class.php on line 305
```

Before this I have change the php.ini file and made

```
  upload_max_filesize = 256M
  post_max_size = 128M
```

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Why don't you run it from a terminal ?

Comment: Neither of those settings that you've changed affect __memory__, and it's a __memory__ error that you're getting

Answer (score 0):

You also need to increase the allowed memory limit in your php.ini - e.g.:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Or directly in the script with ini_set()

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

Still a better solution would be to import it using:

```
mysql -u your_username -p db_name < paht_to_sql_file.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824`;
```

[image]

It can be run at your query in your working database itself.

it is somehow help a lot mostly if we are working a huge records from mysql     database.

Hope it Helps..

Comment: Where should I add this line